# bash file execution

Tags: bash

On OSX El Capitan. I wanted to build my own script which I can call anywhere `meteorB.sh`

The steps:

1. create the file and put the commands in it.
2. chmod u+x of the file and move it to `~/Documents/scripts/meteorB.sh`
3. export PATH="$PATH:~/scripts" line added to my .bash_profile
4. invoke `source ~/.bash_profile`

The error:
Anywhere I type `meteorB.sh` I get:

> -bash: meteorB.sh: command not found

The file has these privileges `-rwxr--r--`
//meteorB.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
meteor remove-platform ios
meteor remove-platform android
meteor npm install --save bcrypt
meteor npm install --save
meteor npm install --production
meteor build .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you added the script to `~/Documents/scripts`, but this directory is not in your PATH.  You added `~/scripts` to your PATH in `.bash_profile`, but not `~/Documents/scripts`.  Change the line in your `.bash_profile` to `export PATH=$PATH:~/Document/scripts` and repeat the other steps.